# Max File Descriptors error docker container on windows host (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am running an application in a docker container. Container is Linux based which fails on startup with error

> 1: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]

The docker host is Windows server 2019 Version 1809 with Docker Engine version 19.03.12 (experimental mode enabled) and does not use Docker for Windows!

To fix the error I have tried:

1. setting higher ulimits using sysctl on the container but get error sysctl: setting
   key "fs.file-max": Read-only file system. Using --privileged flag
   does not help. Get error C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error
   response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode.
2. setting ulimits by adding default-ulimits to the docker run command but get error C:\Program
   Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid option:
   Windows does not support Ulimits.

As far as I can tell this setting should be configured at host level, but that's not possible for Windows Server 2019. Elasticsearch itself gives alternatives for Docker-Desktop and Docker-Machine / WSL [but that's not what I use.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods)

Does anyone know any workaround for this issue?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: When you describe "setting higher limits using sysctl on the container", are you trying to set those inside the container, or using the `--sysctl` flag on `docker run`? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime

Comment: (or `--ulimit` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit)

Comment: tried the sysctl command on the host but that doesnt work since its a linux command and tried it on the docker container via docker exec but that doesnt work since file is read only and I cant start the container privileged (not working in Windows). That having said, the documentation states it should be executed on the host anyway.

The --ulimit flag doesnt work on docker run in Windows either.

Comment: Running it on the (linux) host won't work, because the ulimits are namespaces, and thus can be different inside the container than on the host. The `--ulimit` option should work on Windows as long as the daemon is running on Linux (which it should be if it's running on WSL2). Can you try `docker run --rm --ulimit nofile=65535:65535 busybox sh -c "ulimit -n"` ? That should print `65535`

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're running in Experimental LCOW mode; chances are likely that that's not possible. Note that LCOW no longer maintained, and deprecated in the next (20.10) release of Docker. I'd highly recommend switching to WSL2 if possible